# Best way to initialize objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, object, initialization

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, and I'd like to solve a question I've made up a while ago. Maybe it's something pretty basic, but I'd like to know what's the best way to initialize an object. In some short coding I've made up, I haven't seen visual difference about performance using an 'init' method or directly declaring the values of the parameters in the class. But, when I have a large code with several objects being instantiated, which of those is the best way to instantiate the object, or there's a better alternative than those two?

For example, I have created an interface, MyTestInterface, which uses several classes I've also created in my project:

```
@interface MyTestInterface ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyTestClassOne
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyTestClassTwo

...
```

Each of these classes (MyTestClassOne, MyTestClassTwo, ...) have some other properties, as well the interface itself, that must be initialized. I'd like to clarify my question, for those that haven't understood well, asking if there's a way to initialize the objects of the interface, capable to reduce the memory consumption and compilation time, when it's necessary to instantiate several objects, as in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: your question is unclear. downvote and vote to close. Particularly i'm confused by "constructors"

Comment: I mean, directly initializing the parameters, just like in Java. I think I "might" have malformed my question. Will edit it, thanks @AndreyChernukha

Comment: @DiegoH.Marques i think you should add some code examples. that would be simpler to everyone to EASILY understand what exactly you're meaning

Comment: Oh right. I will post some coding here, thanks again @AndreyChernuka

Comment: That code makes even less sense

Comment: It's just some example, @Popeye. Consider that each object of those has other properties, that may come from NSString to other implemented classes from the project itself. I was just asking which was the best way to setup those objects, that's all.

Comment: When we ask for example to what you mean we aren't asking for the fun of it we're asking because your question doesn't make any sense, and it continues to not make sense with this please include all relevant code not just three lines that don't tell us anything. If you want to know just about them three lines then they will cause errors. My vote to close as **Unclear what you're asking** remains.

Comment: I see. No worries, thanks for explaining, @Popeye. As it was a question itself about generic coding, didn't see much of a problem putting here some example coding. On my next questions, I'll pay more attention. Once again, thank you

Comment: Generic coding questions are fine to ask they just need to make sense and the code needs to make sense and be valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in objective-c initialising an object is done in a classe's designated initialiser or other initialisers. For direct subclasses of NSObject this is generally the 'init' method. You could always use a custom designated initialiser. It is always better to use a initialiser because when you extend a class and there a dependency in a super class that needs to be initialised it will get initialised as you generally call init on a super class when you initialise a object. This init call on the super class works up the chain till it reaches NSObject.

The general way to initialising a class is

```
NameOfClass *myClass = [[NameOfClass alloc] init];

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {

    // you set your default values here
    myLength = 10; //ex
  }
  return self;
}
```

Regarding custom designated initialiser. You can use custom designated initialisers to pass in custom values from other objects

```
NameOfClass *myClass = [[NameOfClass alloc] initWithLength:10];

- (id)initWithLength:(int)length
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {

    // you set your default values here
    myLength = length; //ex
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the very good explanation (I guess I'm really crawling on the floor when it's about Objective-C)

Comment: One more thing, you only initialise the most important objects in the init method or the objects that you need when you subclass the object. others you can initialise anywhere you wish using lazy initialisation. :) we have all be there at some point of time. so dont worry.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it sure is going to be useful

Answer (score 0):

There is some introductory material on Objective-C on Apple's site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

If you're just getting started with Objective-C, it can really be helpful to start with an intro book, like one of these from Big Nerd Ranch:

Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X
[http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-4th-Edition/dp/0321774086/ref=pd_sim_b_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=02AAS1C6T2JMZKJC6DXA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774086)

or

iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide
[http://www.amazon.com/iOS-Programming-Ranch-Edition-Guides/dp/0321821521/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1KBR85MDBKH08Z88873Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521)

Comment: Thank you, it might save my day! Indeed I was looking for some good material, but googling it led me to awful results.